# Angular project structure (folders, routes, services, etc)?

Tags: angularjs

**How the guide for developing large (enterprise) angular web application should be ?**

- Folder structure
- The routes for multiple views
- Modules, configs, services, directives, controllers and personal javascript files.
- Custom filters, views (html)

If your directory structure looks like this (and your app is large) should I modularize like this ? :

> app
>
> - controllers.js
> - filters.js
> - directives.js
> - app.js
> - services.js
> - index.html

Should I inject (include) every installed module in my root **myApp** module or in my submodules ?

```
angular.module('myApp',[
   'tasks',
   'documents',
   'widgets',
   'customModuleForWidgets'
]);
```

or

```
 angular.module('widgets',[
   'customModuleForWidgets'
]);
```

The routes config should be in one place (partent module) or in it's own module ?

```
angular.module('myApp',[
  'ui.router'
])
  .config(['$routeProvider', '$stateProvider', function ($routeProvider, $stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
     .state("widget-areaState", {
       url: "/widget-area",
       templateUrl: 'views/dashboard-widget.html',
       controller: 'widgetCtrl'
     });
     .state(...) // other state
     .state(...) // other state
  })
;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check this [guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide) by John Papa. It contains a lot of various things and a project structure among them. It's quite a good guide to start a big angular projects with a lot of how-to's. You can decide yourself on each exact item if you want to follow it or not, but most seem very reasonable. He suggests folder by feature in case of structure:

```
app/
    app.module.js
    app.config.js
    components/
        calendar.directive.js
        calendar.directive.html
        user-profile.directive.js
        user-profile.directive.html
    layout/
        shell.html
        shell.controller.js
        topnav.html
        topnav.controller.js
    people/
        attendees.html
        attendees.controller.js
        people.routes.js
        speakers.html
        speakers.controller.js
        speaker-detail.html
        speaker-detail.controller.js
    services/
        data.service.js
        localstorage.service.js
        logger.service.js
        spinner.service.js
    sessions/
        sessions.html
        sessions.controller.js
        sessions.routes.js
        session-detail.html
        session-detail.controller.js
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use project structure like this.

[image]